# Mysql query for all subcategories in json format - Opencart tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, opencart

I have the following query for getting categories in json format with subcategories up to two levels from standard Opencart tables.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(json) FROM
(
SELECT  
  CONCAT('{"folder":true,"key":',c0.category_id,',"title":"',cd0.`name`,'", "select":', CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET (c0.category_id, 387) THEN "true" ELSE "false" END ,

  ',"children":[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"title":"', cd1.name, '", "key":"',c1.category_id,'", "select":', CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET (c1.category_id, 387) THEN "true" ELSE "false" END ,

  ',"children":[', (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"title":"', cd2.`name`, '", "key":"', cd2.category_id,'", "select":', CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET (c2.category_id, 387) THEN "true" ELSE "false" END , '}'), '')
FROM oc_category c2
JOIN oc_category_description cd2 ON c2.category_id = cd2.category_id WHERE c2.parent_id = c1.category_id
), ']}')), ']}') AS json
FROM
  oc_category c0
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_description cd0  
    ON (c0.category_id = cd0.category_id)  
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_to_store c1s0  
    ON (c0.category_id = c1s0.category_id)  
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp0
    ON (c0.category_id = cp0.category_id)
  LEFT JOIN oc_category c1
    ON (c0.category_id = c1.parent_id)  
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_description cd1
    ON (c1.category_id = cd1.category_id)  
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp1  
    ON (c1.category_id = cp1.category_id)
WHERE c0.status = '1'  
  AND c0.`parent_id` = 0
  AND c1.`parent_id` > 0
  AND cp0.level = 0
  AND cp1.level = 1
  AND c1s0.store_id = 0
  AND cd0.language_id = 1
 GROUP BY c1s0.store_id, cd0.language_id, c0.parent_id, cd0.`name`
ORDER BY c1.sort_order,
    c0.sort_order,
    LCASE(cd1.name)
    ) cat;
```

It's returning json like this:

```
    {
        "folder":true,
        "key":1,
        "title":"Test",
        "select":false,
        "children":[
          {
          "title":"Testsub",
          "key":"371",
          "select":false,
          "children":[
             {
               "title":"Test 6",
               "key":"392",
               "select":false
             },
            {
              "title":"Test 5",
              "key":"391",
              "select":false
            }
            ]
         }
       ]
    }
```

It's preety criptic. But what it does it's returning categories with subcategories in json format. I want now to update this query for more sub/sub categories so G test 5 and G Test 6 also they have "children" with subcategories, and also one more level. But I am preety lost about this brackets and how to accomplish that, categories are connected with parent_id. If anyone can update this function to include more level children subcategories that would be of very help for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you could provide an example of the 'expected' json result... it would go a long way to helping you figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: And you really shouldn't (its confusing? a mess?) be trying to concat and build all the json inside of the SQL query. Do it in arrays with results first, then just json_encode the whole final multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I know but I have existing mysql function that is doing this and I just want to update it.

Comment: Updating a bad approach isn't a good way to go. @IncredibleHat has a good point. Building a JSON string isn't a strong point for MySQL, but is for PHP.

Comment: Ok thanks I will consider that.

Comment: Why not do the encoding in php like everybody else !?!?!?